# Why the "Group BY" by month didn't work?

Tags: postgresql

Why the result of this query is always one :

SELECT stats1.cnt1 FROM staging.memberships_autoship_box b JOIN staging.memberships_autoship a ON a.id = b.autoship_box_id JOIN (SELECT COUNT(bn.autoship_box_id) cnt1,bn.autoship_box_id FROM staging.memberships_autoship_box bn GROUP BY bn.autoship_box_id ) stats1 ON 
(stats1.autoship_box_id = a.id)

Comment: Could you give us the error that this query is throwing? And maybe provide a little more description on the question rather than such a vague "Why doesn't this work?"

Comment: You've been a SO member for 6 months. You should take the time to read [how to format your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) (especially code blocks).

Comment: This is a really good resource for improving SQL questions on SO https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: When I format the code, I'm not able to save. very sorry

Answer (score 3):

The `group by` clause, unlike the `order by` clause, doesn't take column ordinals. In this clause, `1` and `2` are just integer literals, and since every row of your query has the same value for these two literals, they are all grouped in to a single result row.

Instead, you should use the actual columns from your query:

```
GROUP BY sql_activity_days.styleship_start_month, memberCountSql."122_days"
```